# EXCEL VBA Formula - Pad a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to pad an XLS cell via VBA & XLS Formula but I am stumbling:

Example:  I want to append " - Test" to the contents of Cell AC2 via a formula, then paste that formula to all the remaining rows in Col AC:

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
strTest = " - Test"

'append

Range("AC2:AC2").Formula = "=AC2.value & value(strTest)"

'then cut and paste

Range("AC2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("AC2:A" & lastRow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

I am guessing I need to adjust the syntax of the formula to append.  I've tried several variants without success.

Any suggestions?

Note:  the following formula works, but only in the first row.  Copy & Paste simply copies the VALUE from X2 into subsequent rows, not the formula:

```
 Range("X2:X2").Formula = Range("AC2:AC2").Value & strTest
 Range("X2").Select
 Selection.Copy
 Range("X2:X" & lastRow).Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
     SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: That would create a circular reference. Why do you want a formula in there?

Comment: I want to append the same string to the TAIL of each cell in Column AC.  I don't know the number of rows in advance. 

Cutting & pasting the formula seemed a direct approach

Comment: Do the cells contain formulas or values currently?

Comment: The original Cells in column AC contain simple text, no formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append `strTest` to the cell values, you can use:

```
With Range("X2:X" & lastRow)
    .Value2 = .Worksheet.Evaluate("Index(" & .Address & "&""" & strTest & """,)")
End With
```

Comment: I hate those pesky triple quotes! :)

Answer (score -1):

I think instead of this:

```
Range("AC2:AC2").Formula = "=AC2.value & value(strTest)"
```

You want this:

```
Range("AC2:AC2").Formula = "=AC2.value & value(" & strTest & ")"
```